# CRAN packages dependency on bioconductor packages

Tags: r, cran, bioconductor

The packages gRbase, gRain and gRim (which I maintain) all use functionality from the packages RBGL, graph and Rgraphviz on Bioconductor. This means that users can not install my packages directly (the must do setRepositories -> BioC software). This is not the largest problem in the world, surely, but it is so large a problem that it causes people trouble or make some people give up on using my packages.

My question is: Is there anyway of specifying, for example in DESCRIPTION, that RBGL, graph and Rgraphviz must be installed from Bioconductor so that users of my packages do neet this trouble? It would be excellent if there was a way around this problem.

Best regards
Søren

Comment: You could add them to `Suggests:` instead of `Imports:`, as a sneaky way to allow them to  be imported but not an installation failure if they aren't available. For this to be safer, though, I also suggest: (1) ensure any tests fail gracefully if not present; (2) add a test in `.onAttach` or similar that reminds users to install them; (3) any code that uses them add a layer of checks to insulate the user from `function not found` errors, instead a clear error message of `package "harbuzz" from Bioconductor not found`. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a line that says `biocViews:` in your `DESCRIPTION` file. In that case, it will also check Bioconductor for package dependencies and install them from there.